# Lenovo Synaptics touch pad driver installation

Tags: windows-8, drivers, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I want to install a Synaptics touchpad driver on my Lenovo G710 laptop.

I downloaded a new touchpad driver from the Lenovo support website. It said it was for Synaptics, Elan, Alps. I clicked to install, and it looked like it was going to install Synaptics, which is what I want; but the text was cut off so I wasn't sure. No choice was made available. When I continued, I got a box saying that ELAN was being installed.

I've checked around on this site, especially the suggested questions that appeared as I typed this question, and tried going to the device manager and picking a driver to update. The choices there are Lenovo and PS/2.

Comment: Could you provide specific device details about the touchpad itself?  I am trying to determine what type of touchpad you have exactly.  I am specifically looking for A device identification information from `Device Manger`.

Comment: Does this help? ELAN, 7/31/2013, VERSION 11.4.25.1  Device ACPI\ETD060E\4&2fbd9b47&0

Comment: You have an Elan touchpad device.  Synaptics device driver isn't going to work with it based on the deviceid.

Comment: Thanks. What about the PS/2? It's one of the options I get when I browse the Lenovo Pointing Device update via device driver.

Comment: It isn't really relevant to your case.  The `Synaptics` driers are not for the particular device model you have.

Comment: I'm running Windows 8.1, so I'm guessing that the PS/2 driver comes pre-installed as part of Windows. Is that also Synaptics?

Answer (score 0):

This was my situation with Lenovo Edge Windows 10 Synaptics driver. See whether this helps. 
I was using Windows 10 in my Lenovo Edge 15.
It happened suddenly. Double finger touch wasnt working. So I've uninstalled Syaptics driver and tried reinstalling the driver which I've downloaded from Lenovo/Synaptics website. 
After installation, it errored "Synaptic device not found".

With this state, just go to **`Device Manager`** under **`Control Panel`**.
Under `Mice and other pointing devices`, right click `Lenovo Pointing Devices` **`>`**  `Update Driver Software...`

Finish it and restart the machine. This should work.